# AEM 6.3 - Filter.xml merge mode not respected with Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, filter, adobe, aem, jackrabbit

I am using AEM archetype, Maven with my AEM project.

My site configuration is version controlled and exists at *ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/conf/project-name*. It contains templates, template types and policies.

My header and footer component are using a design dialog and storing a couple properties, and a multifield in a policy for each. So this contents gets stored down in */conf/project-name*.

```
<header jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <policy_1547171225060
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      jcr:title="Header"
      sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/policy/policy"
      alttext=""
      heading="">
      <jcr:content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
      <headerPrimaryLinks jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
      <headerSecondaryLinks jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
    </policy_1547171225060>
</header>
<footer jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
  <policy_1547176219602
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      jcr:title="Footer"
      sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/policy/policy"
      alttext=""
      copyright="">
      <jcr:content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
      <footerTopLinks jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
      <footerBottomLinks jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
      <footerSocialLinks jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
  </policy_1547176219602>
</footer>
```

I have also defined some workspace filters at *ui.apps/src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
  <filter root="/apps/project-name"/>
  <filter root="/apps/sling"/>
  <filter root="/conf/project-name" mode="merge"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

When I run a Maven build and create my apps package and import it to AEM using the package manager, then reinstall it, my content is retained for the header and footer. But...

If I run a Jenkins build with CRX plugin my content gets erased/replaced. It doesn't seem that my merge mode is being respected for */conf/project-name* and therefore not correctly keeping the entered content. Why would this be happening?

Comment: CRX Plug-in? Can you please add details on that? The traditional way of building from Jenkins is using a maven build to create the package then running a curl command to deploy that package. To remain consistent with how the autoInstallPackage profile work.

Comment: Please check if there are conflicting `filter` settings in the `pom.xml` or in the build pipeline. You could check in the package manager if the filter contains unexpected values.

Comment: Are you using the [Maven CRX Plugin](https://github.com/Cognifide/Maven-CRX-Plugin) or the [Content Package Maven Plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/pl/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/vlt-mavenplugin.html)? Your project structure implies it's probably the latter but you mentioned the first one in your question.

Comment: Fixed the issue by moving the /conf/project-name directory to ui.content, instead of ui.apps.